# how to find last value of array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array in javascript. I have to find last value of that array. 
My code is like

```
var array= fruits;
```

and I have to find last fruit in that array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find number of elements in array and store it on variable like

```
var total = array.length;
```

Now you can find last value of array using below code

```
var last = array[total-1];
```

Comment: What is the last value in `[0,1,,,]`?

Answer (score 5):

Since in JavaScript arrays of size `n` are indexed from `[0..n-1]`, you can get the last element by simply indexing the array at `n-1`, where is the length of the array and can be obtained by the `.length` property:

```
var lastFruit = array[array.length - 1];
```

If you want to get the last element and also remove it from the array, you can use the `.pop` methid:

```
var lastFruit = array.pop(); // get last element of array and remove it from array
```

**Note:** As RobG stated:

> `length` is **at least** one more than the highest index, but might be
>   greater

Comment: Not necessarily, *length* is **at least** one more than the highest index, but it might be greater: `[0,1,,,]` has length 4 (except for buggy versions of IE where *length* is 5) but the highest member is at *1*, the higher members don't exist.

Comment: I get your point. However, even if a have this array `[0,1,,,]`, then it'll be evaluated to `[0,1,undefined,undefined,undefined]`, so the length is really `5`.

Comment: No, the length is 4 and there are no members with index 2 and 3, they don't exist. It's the same as `var a = [0,1]; a.length = 4;`. Accessing `a[3]` returns *undefined* for the same reason that `a[100]` returns *undefined*: because that is the value that is returned when accessing a non–existent property of an Object (and Arrays are Objects). It doesn't mean the property exists: `'100' in a` returns *false*.

Comment: Hm, you're right. I agree with you now. But anyway, OP didn't specify about this case, so I suppose he's using a normal array. But I'll update the answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

You accomplish this by using the length of the array (fruits.length) and subtracting 1 (because the array is 0 indexed). For instance...

```
fruits[0]="pear";
fruits[1]="apple";
fruits[2]="peach";
```

So fruits.length would be 3, so fruits.length - 1 = 2. So to get the last element...

```
var lastFruit = fruits[fruits.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have to find last value of that array

The length property is **at least** one higher than the highest index, however it might be higher in which case the *n-1* member may not exist. E.g.

```
// Create an array with length 10
var a = new Array(10);

// Add one member at index 0
a[0] = 'foo';
```

So the "last" value of the array is at index 0 and has a value of "foo". So you can start with *length - 1* and search backwards for members that actually exist:

```
function lastValue(arr) {
  var i = arr.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (i in arr) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
  // If get to here, arr has no members
  return -1;
}

// All the following arrays have length 4 but different number of members
console.log(lastValue([ , , , ,]));  // -1, i.e. there are no members
console.log(lastValue([0,1, , ,]));  //  1
console.log(lastValue([0,1,2,3 ]));  //  3
console.log(lastValue([ , , ,3 ]));  //  3
```

If you know the Array only has numeric members (i.e. there are no non-numeric properties and no negative properties) you can do:

```
var arr = [,,'foo',,'bar',,]; // length 6, highest member is at index 4

console.log(arr[Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(arr))]); // 'bar'
```

Requires ES5 *Object.keys*.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can find it's length then you know the last index, and can get the item from it

```
var last_item = array[array.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its as easy as:

```
fruits[fruits.length-1]
```